# Computing product of lots of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, products

I'm trying to compute the first column of $M$ where

$$M=(A - x_1I)(A - x_2I)\cdots(A - x_rI)$$

where $A$ is in $R^{n \times n}$ and $x$ is a vector in $R^r$.

Whatever way I think of it, it requires compute every single column of $A_i=A-x_iI$. There doesn't seem to be anyway around that.

Can anyone suggest a way to compute this?

Does the fact that $A$ is written as $(A - x_1I)$ help in any way?

Comment: I don't see an immediate way around computing $A^k e_1$. How does $r$ relate to $n$? Does $A$ have any nice factorisation?

Comment: There's no relation between $r$ and $n$. They are just arbitrary.

Comment: It may not help, but if $r > n$ you can compute $A^r$ from the characteristic polynomial.